# Asynchronously assembling a complex object

Tags: c#, async-await

Sanity check needed, as I'm still very unfamiliar with the nuances behind async/await and how they relate to more traditional Task / TPL code.

I have a high-level repository layer which is assembling a business object from various lower-level repositories.  As a business decision, we are doing keyed lookups at the data layer and assembling the composite object in code.  In the following code, "Account" is the business object, and the various _tAccountXXXRepo objects are all patterned similarly to this (we are using NPoco):

```
public class T_AccountMapperRepository : BaseNPocoRepository<T_AccountMapper>
    , IRetrieveMany<T_AccountMapper>
    , IRetrieve<AccountId, T_AccountMapper>
{
    public T_AccountMapperRepository(IDatabase database) : base(database)
    {
    }

    public async Task<T_AccountMapper> Retrieve(AccountId input)
    {
        return await Database.QueryAsync<T_AccountMapper>()
            .First(x => x.AccountId == input)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The code to fetch the different values *can* be logically executed in parallel, and I am wondering if this implementation is the correct pattern to do so:  (the various methods being called on the Account object are thread-safe as well)

```
public async Task<Account> Retrieve(AccountId input1, DateTime input2)
{
    var account = new Account();

    await Task.WhenAll(
        _tAccountMapperRepo.Retrieve(input1)
            .ContinueWith(async result => account.SetAccountMap(await TranslateAccountMap(result))),

        _tPaymentRedirectionRepo.Retrieve(input1, input2)
            .ContinueWith(async result => account.ChangePayerToAccount(await TranslatePaymentRedirection(result))),

        _tAccountAncestorRepo.Retrieve(input1, input2)
            .ContinueWith(async result => await _tAccountMapperRepo.Retrieve((await result).AncestorId))
            .ContinueWith(async result => account.MoveAccountToNewParentAccountMap(await TranslateAccountMap(await result))),

        _tAccountRepo.Retrieve(input1)
            .ContinueWith(async result => await _tAccountTypeRepo.Retrieve((await result).TypeId))
            .ContinueWith(async result => account.SetAccountType(await TranslateAccountType(await result)))
    );

    return account;
}
```

Any method that is labelled with TranslateXXX all look similar to this:

```
private static async Task<AccountMap> TranslateAccountMap(Task<T_AccountMapper> mapTask)
{
    if (!mapTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(mapTask), mapTask.Exception);

    var map = await mapTask;

    return new AccountMap(map.AccountId, map.Login, map.Namespace);
}
```

My main concerns are mixing Task and async/await, and whether or not my async & awaiting is re-introducing an element of synchronicity in what I'm hoping to make a very asynchronous process.  My end goal is that as many various properties as possible are fetched in parallel and assembled

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Please do not use the name `result` in your `ContinueWith` delegates. They are really misleading. Because you haven't specified `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` that's why your ancestor / antecedent task could have failed. IMO, calling a failed task as `result` is misleading.

Comment: I updated your title to what I **think** your code is doing from the description you provided. This allows people looking to answer questions find such questions that are related to their domain interests instead of having to rely on what you as the reviewee **think** your problem is. It also makes for a better variety of titles :) I hope this also clarifies what BCdotWEB wanted from your title.

Comment: @Vogel612: that isn't what my question was though, unfortunately.  I was specifically looking to know if the way I was mixing & matching async/await with Task.ContinueWith was going to cause deadlocks or synchronization problems.

Comment: that is **exactly** the point. The title is ***not*** what your question about the code is, it's what the **code is doing**.

Comment: @Vogel612: So then I should have asked on a different Stack Exchange site, is ultimately what I'm gathering.

Comment: well, the problem with that is, that for Stack Overflow, while it's a specific question you have, a lot of people think that it belongs here on Code Review. And overall code review **is** a better fit than SO, so they're not even wrong. It's not a perfect fit, but it works well enough, I'd say. Other programming-related stack exchanges fit even less than SO, soo...

Comment: I mean, ultimately you guys control the format, I'm just of the opinion that anything could be happening asynchronously, so bucketing it to "assemble an object" misses the point.  Is it up to the reader to recognize that "fetching these 4 URLs is exactly the same use-case as 'building a domain object'"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on feedback from aepot, and lessons from [AspNetCore Async Guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-await-over-continuewith), this is what I refactored the code into:

```
public async Task<Account> RetrieveAsync(AccountId input1, DateTime input2)
{
    Account account = new Account();

    await Task.WhenAll(
        SetAccountMap(account, input1, input2),
        ChangePayer(account, input1, input2),
        SetParentMap(account, input1, input2),
        SetAccountType(account, input1, input2)
    );

    return account;
}

private async Task SetAccountType(Account account, AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var baseAccount = await _tAccountRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId);
    var accountType = await _tAccountTypeRepo.RetrieveAsync(baseAccount.TypeId); 
    var convertedAccountType = _accountTypeConverter.Convert(accountType);

    account.SetAccountType(convertedAccountType);
}

private async Task SetParentMap(Account account, AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var accountAncestor = await _tAccountAncestorRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId, dateTime);
    var accountMap = await _tAccountMapperRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountAncestor.DescendentId);
    var convertedAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(accountMap);

    account.MoveAccountToNewParentAccountMap(convertedAccountMap);
}

private async Task ChangePayer(Account account, AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var paymentRedirection = await _tPaymentRedirectionRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId, dateTime);
    var convertedPaymentRedirection = _paymentRedirectionConverter.Convert(paymentRedirection);

    account.ChangePayerToAccount(convertedPaymentRedirection);
}

private async Task SetAccountMap(Account account, AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var accountMap = await _tAccountMapperRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId);
    var convertedAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(accountMap);

    account.SetAccountMap(convertedAccountMap);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to rename `input1` and `input2` to `id` and `date` accordingly. `accountId` and `dateTime` arguments can be shorten in the same way. Btw, I like this version of the code, looks more friendly.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher With this code you are running 4 different functions concurrently that are try to modify the same object. It can work (and will not cause race condition) if these functions are working on independent set of properties of the Account. What if you would do the necessary data retrievals concurrently and then you could construct the Account object on a single thread? With that your ET(L) would be nicely separated. Parallel Extraction and Single threaded Transformation.

Comment: @PeterCsala: in this case the object is thread-aware and there will not be race conditions.  Good catch though, because that could definitely be problematic!  Can you post an answer that would illustrate the parallel-fetch & single-threaded set?  I feel like it may bring a bunch of noise back to the main method.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher I've just posted an answer, please check it.

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the most helpful answer or your own to make the review complete.

Comment: @aepot: I had to wait before accepting -- I upvoted yours, but will be accepting mine since ultimately that's what I went with.

Answer (score 3):

As for me it looks fine except one thing. You have already completed `Task` in `.ContinueWith` block, thus you may use `.Result` then instead of `await` and avoid redundant `async` State Machine.

By the way, if you're using `async/await`, probably there's no continuations needed.

Consider this continuations-free implementation of 1st `Task.WhenAll()` job.

```cs
public async Task<Account> Retrieve(AccountId input1, DateTime input2)
{
    var account = new Account();

    // probably try-catch wrapper maybe useful here as replacement of !mapTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully
    await Task.WhenAll((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        T_AccountMapper map = await _tAccountMapperRepo.Retrieve(input1);
        // continuation:
        AccountMap accountMap = new AccountMap(map.AccountId, map.Login, map.Namespace);
        account.SetAccountMap(accountMap);
    })
    //, (Func<Task>)(async() => {...})
    );

    return account;
}
```

As you can see, `TranslateAccountMap` method isn't needed anymore.

Finally, it's up to you.

P.S. Here's a [useful link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/).

Comment: The "useful link" was already purple :) That's what gave me something like the pattern

Answer (score 3):

Here I've two alternative versions of Bryan Boettcher revised code.

In his version there are 4 *ETL* functions and they are running concurrently.

In my solutions only the *Extract* part is running concurrently. The *Transformation* and *Load* parts are executed sequentially.

#### Alternative #1

Please bear in mind that I had to use some made up type names (like: `AccountType`, `PaymentRedirection`) because I could not tell the exact types based on the provided code.

```cs
public async Task<Account> RetrieveAsync(AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    //Extract
    var accountTypeJob = RetrieveAccountType(accountId);
    var paymentRedirectionJob = RetrievePaymentRedirection(accountId, dateTime);
    var accountMapJob = RetrieveAccountMap(accountId);
    var parentAccountMapJob = RetrieveAccountMapForParent(accountId, dateTime);

    //Transform
    var accountType = await accountTypeJob;
    var convertedAccountType = _accountTypeConverter.Convert(accountType);

    var paymentRedirection = await paymentRedirectionJob;
    var convertedPaymentRedirection = _paymentRedirectionConverter.Convert(paymentRedirection);

    var accountMap = await accountMapJob;
    var convertedAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(accountMap);

    var parentAccountMap = await parentAccountMapJob;
    var convertedParentAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(parentAccountMap);

    //Load
    var account = new Account();
    account.SetAccountType(convertedAccountType);
    account.ChangePayerToAccount(convertedPaymentRedirection);
    account.SetAccountMap(convertedAccountMap);
    account.MoveAccountToNewParentAccountMap(convertedParentAccountMap);
    return account;
}

private async Task<AccountType> RetrieveAccountType(AccountId accountId)
{
    var baseAccount = await _tAccountRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId);
    return await _tAccountTypeRepo.RetrieveAsync(baseAccount.TypeId);
}

private async Task<AccountMap> RetrieveAccountMapForParent(AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var accountAncestor = await _tAccountAncestorRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId, dateTime);
    return await _tAccountMapperRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountAncestor.DescendentId);
}

private async Task<PaymentRedirection> RetrievePaymentRedirection(AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    return await _tPaymentRedirectionRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId, dateTime);
}

private async Task<AccountMap> RetrieveAccountMap(AccountId accountId)
{
    return await _tAccountMapperRepo.RetrieveAsync(accountId);
}
```

As you can see I have 4 `RetrieveXYZ` functions and these are responsible for loading data. I suppose these are I/O operations, so they are not CPU-bound (concurrency is not limited by the available cores).

During the *Extract* phase I start all of the `Task`s, so there is no need to explicitly call the `Task.WhenAll` In the *Transform* phase I access the retrieved data via the `await` keywords.

#### Alternative #2

With a simple helper function we can make the `RetrieveAsync` function neater and more concise.

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<(T1, T2, T3, T4)> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2, Task<T3> t3, Task<T4> t4)
    {
        return (await t1, await t2, await t3, await t4);
    }
}
```

By taking advantage of this helper method the new version of the `RetrieveAsync` would look like this:

```cs
public async Task<Account> RetrieveAsync(AccountId accountId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    //Extract
    var (accountType, paymentRedirection, accountMap, parentAccountMap) = await TaskExtensions.WhenAll(
        RetrieveAccountType(accountId), RetrievePaymentRedirection(accountId, dateTime),
        RetrieveAccountMap(accountId), RetrieveAccountMapForParent(accountId, dateTime));

    //Transform
    var convertedAccountType = _accountTypeConverter.Convert(accountType);
    var convertedPaymentRedirection = _paymentRedirectionConverter.Convert(paymentRedirection);
    var convertedAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(accountMap);
    var convertedParentAccountMap = _accountMapConverter.Convert(parentAccountMap);

    //Load
    var account = new Account();
    account.SetAccountType(convertedAccountType);
    account.ChangePayerToAccount(convertedPaymentRedirection);
    account.SetAccountMap(convertedAccountMap);
    account.MoveAccountToNewParentAccountMap(convertedParentAccountMap);
    return account;
}
```

#### Advantages

- Only the I/O bound operations are running concurrently

  - Each helper function has single responsibility
  - The top-level function acts as a coordinator
- There is no shared resource, so we don't have to worry that much about thread-safety

#### Disadvantages

- If the *Transform* and/or *Load* parts are I/O bound as well then this approach would be slower
- It is not relying on the built-in `Task.WhenAll` rather than it relies on the `ValueTuple` and C# 7's Deconstruction capabilities, so it can't be used in older .NET Framework versions.